# Can the word mountain be used as the meaning of burden?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-meaning

I was listening to a song named 'Nobody loves me like you' by Chris Tomlin.
And there was an expression that You’re breaking down the weight of all my mountains.
Thinking by context I guess the mountain in this lyrics means burden or guilty. But I wanna make it clear.

**1. Can mountain be used as the meaning of burden?**

And I wanna ask one more thing.
**2. "What a song to sing." What does this mean exactly?**
Does it mean there is no song to sing to express this kind of love?

The following is the lyrics of the song.
Thanks in advance.

*Morning, I see You in the sunrise every morning

It’s like a picture that You’ve painted for me

A love letter in the sky*

*Story, I could’ve had a really different story

But You came down from Heaven to restore me

Forever saved my life*

*Nobody loves me like You love me Jesus

I stand in awe of Your amazing ways

I worship You as long as I am breathing

God, You are faithful and true

Nobody loves me like You*

***Mountains, You’re breaking down the weight of all my mountains***
Even when it feels like I’m surrounded
You never leave my side

***Oh, what a song to sing***
Jesus, You love me
And I love You God

Comment: The song certainly has no scriptural content, if that is what you are asking. You would have to go outside of scripture to find any meaning to attach to it.

Comment: @NigelJ I am not asking about scriptural usage of the mountain. I am asking about general usage in English.

Comment: The second question is probably off-topic (poetic interpretation) for this forum, and might be more appropriate in MusicFans or Literature.

Comment: The expression is certainly idiomatic in English. We talk of a 'mountain of debt' and guilt can also be so expressed. Faith moves mountains, of course [Matthew 21:21](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/40021021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the sense that a "**burden**" can be a "**heavy load**", it can be used as an allegory. As an object of and relating to a true act of Biblical faith, **a mountain is allegorically used** to describe **something that would normally be too heavy (or large) to move**. See Mark 11:23, Bible.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/burden

> **Mark 11:23** KJV: "*For verily I say unto you, That whosoever shall say unto this **mountain**, **Be thou removed, and be thou cast into the
>   sea**; and shall not doubt in his heart, but shall believe that those
>   things which he saith shall come to pass; he shall have whatsoever he
>   saith.*"

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/allegory

The same mountain allegory is easily transferrable and can thereby be applied to other contemporary situations. It can allegorically be made into many things - all suggesting great difficulty or apparent impossibility (in this case a ***burden too great to bear***).

> The meaning of the phrase "**Oh what a song to sing**"? I would hazard
>   to suppose (**referring to your second question**) that the author of
>   the song is deriving joy out of singing the song. It is an exclamation
>   of "**exaltation**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exaltation

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question #1, it *could* mean burden, that depends on the author.  But "burden" wouldn't be a common symbolic usage of mountain.  A more conventional use (that kind of fits the context of the song) would be "obstacle."

See http://symbolism.wikia.com/wiki/Mountain:

> Some of the things that a mountain or range of mountains can symbolize:
>
> - obstacles.
> - climbing over one or passing through a range indicates overcoming obstacles or making progress.
> - climbing up a mountain or other height often indicates spiritual or mental "rising" or improvement.
> - permanence and immovability

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question listening to this song. My feeling is that it relates to the allegorical mountain that can be moved by faith the size of a mustard seed. The mountain in that case was the heavy burden the disciples faced trying to cast out the demon in a possessed person.